# What are recommended methods/tools for cloning Control Panel layouts?

Tags: control-panel, publish-layout

I've got an MSM installation where I need to clone **Control Panel 'Publish' layouts** for site A to site B, for channels and corresponding field groups that have already been duplicated from site A to site B.

I've looked in to cloning the layouts directly in **exp_layout_publish** but, with about 100 fields in the main field group used, the minified JSON way that layouts are defined is kind of daunting.

It makes me wonder if it wouldn't be more robust just to recreate the layouts manually.

Unless, that is, anyone can suggest something better.

Does anyone have experience and advice they can offer with the following in EE 2.6.x (ideally with an MSM setup):

- [MX Toolbox](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-tool-box) (free): but has [2.6.x issues](http://www.eec.ms/forums/viewthread/22/P15/#2155)
- [Clone Layout Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/clone-layout-module) (free): Kind of recommends using MX Toolbox
- [Blueprints](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/blueprints) ($45)

Any insights would be most welcome.